# How to detect debug mode in jinja?

Tags: python, debugging, flask, jinja2

Under flask, I want to include/exclude stuff in the jinja template based upon whether, or not, we are in debug mode.  I'm not debating if this is a good, or bad, idea (i'd vote 'bad' but want to do it just for this case nonetheless :-), so how might this best happen?

I was hoping i would not have to pass the variable explicitly into the template, unlike this:

```
render_template('foo.html', debug=app.debug)
```

not that this would be too hard, but I'd rather just magically say in the template:

```
{% if debug %}
      go crazzzzy
{% endif %}
```

Is there some default variable just lazing about waiting for me to pounce?

Comment: Have you considered setting `g.debug` based on some other debug switch mechanism (other config variables/files, including `config`, see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-context) and have the template use that?

Comment: @metatoaster nice idea but, after some toying around, nup, no joy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use [context processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templating/#context-processors)

> To inject new variables automatically into the context of a template, context processors exist in Flask. Context processors run before the template is rendered and have the ability to inject new values into the template context. A context processor is a function that returns a dictionary. The keys and values of this dictionary are then merged with the template context, for all templates in the app:

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_debug():
    return dict(debug=app.debug)
```

now `debug` variable accessible in templates.

Answer (score 11):

When you run your flask application with `app.run(debug=True)`, you can also just check the `config` object like so:

```
{% if config['DEBUG'] %}
    <h1>My html here</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This it documented here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/templating/ 

> Changed in version 0.10: This is now always available, even in imported templates.
> New in version 0.6.